# Sample Metaphor for Cycling

Tags: creative-writing

Can you please give me a sample metaphor for cycling, specially when pedalling uphill and sweating.

Also, I'd like an example of a metaphor to describe the opposite situation: riding downhill, with the wind is blowing into the driver's face and the speed is increasing.

I'm composing a speech project with a requirements of using metaphors.

**Edit**: I want to have a metaphor for an uphill ride and a downhill ride experience.

Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? A metaphor is a comparison. Are you comparing cycling to X, or X to cycling?

Comment: Thanks - this is a much clearer question :) Metaphors are generally used to convey a certain emotion or resonance - any idea what it is you'd like to get across with your metaphor for cycling? Or, what is it you'll be trying to _say_ about cycling - e.g. that it's a huge thrill, or that it's hard work, or an overview of cycling as a professional sport...?

Comment: as a policy on this site we usually try not to give you the exact answer to your question if it's homework, but we will help you in the right direction.

Comment: @justkt its not a homework and I'm not studying anymore

Comment: Sorry for leaping to conclusions. It's simply that a project with a requirement of using metaphors is, well, an assignment. It might not be a _homework_ assignment, but it seems pretty clear that your question is "I was assigned to do X, how do I do X." I think it's appropriate to treat that in the same way as a homework assignment, even if the assignment wasn't from school.

Comment: This is an old question but isn't it off topic as asking what to write?

Answer (score 4):

A few examples:

- Pedaling uphill is like swimming against the current; downhill gives you the brief instant of going over the waterfall.
- Uphill is like a sweaty, physical manifestation of how I felt dragging myself into the office every morning for five years. Down is the horrible moment you realize that being fired is even worse.
- When you're pedaling uphill, you're eight years old again, lugging around the lawnmower to make five bucks. Then you rush downhill - that's when you've got the five dollars, and you're soaring to the candy store as fast as your little legs can carry you.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the situation: You pedal uphill, your muscles are aching, your face is a grimace of pain. There is resistance (called gravity) which does not want that you reach the top of the hill.

Where do you feel resistance in other situations? Where else is a force you have to overbear, to conquer? Use that as metaphor.

Now going downhill: It's easy riding downhill. You feel free. Gravity is on your side (The force is with you). When do you feel like that? Parachuting? Find out and pick your metaphor.